# System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=3.8.5.0 breaks call to OnApplyTemplate()

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a complex Windows Phone 7 class library which has been working well for months. However, making only a one line change to the class library, in the csproj file, causes failure of the code. The one line in question is this one:

from:

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=3.7.5.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

to:

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=3.8.5.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

the failure I refer to is the fact that the OnApplyTemplate() overload, essential to the correct functioning of our class library, is no longer called.

Can anybody please give me any insight into this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not "making only a one line change to the class library". You're referencing a different version of an external, albeit system, library.

If there were two different versions of a library I would expect there to be a difference between them. (Otherwise have the 2 versions?) It just so happens that the change between the 2 versions appears to be a breaking change for you.

Why change to v 3.8.5.0 in the first place?